# TFS 2015 Virtual Dir

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Customer installed TFS 2015 removing the tfs/ virtual directory so the url would be shorter like http://tfsserver/

Now, I am evaluating the migration to 2017 version and I would like to know if there will be any problem, cause I think I will need to keep this "configuration" for the sake of client connectivity.

Many thanks for all your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It won't cause a problem. When you upgrade, you'll have the option to redo all of the site bindings.